# Is there a way to clear out the Zipkin database?

Tags: zipkin

As a developer using Zipkin in a Docker container on my local dev box, I would like to clear out the traces from time to time to prevent build up and to allow easier identification of what I am looking for.

Is there an easy way to clear all traces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default config stores traces in memory so restarting the zipkin instance should clear all the traces. Otherwise, if it's configured to use a database, you could connect to the database and manually truncate tables containing the traces.